# Spring backend, and gwt frontend, separation of concerns?

Tags: spring, gwt

We are about to embark on a new project development which is basically a Back-office application.

We chose the following technologies in our backend:

Spring, JPA, mySQL , MongoDB, RabbitMQ..

We chose to use GWT as our frontend framework.

My question is very simple:

Should we create one project, that comprises both the backend and frontend?

OR:

Should we create 2 separate project, one will be a pure backend project while the other pure frontend?

EDIT - we are a team of 4 developers each should get his hands dirty in an end-to-end development. i.e everyone in the team should code features from client to server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on different parameters, like final size of the project, number of team members, etc.

But in general I'd rather split projects in maven modules, because it allows a better client/server sides separation, it facilitates testing, and it's more convenient when you have people in the project focused in one side.

If you go ahead with this setup, I suggest to take a look to Tomas Broyer's [archetypes](https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes)

[EDITED]
Knowing that you are a team of 4 people and you are going to work for 8 months, I definitively will go with a multi-module maven project (server, shared, client).

Comment: Is the project going to be big (lines of code)? how many months have you estimated to be working on?

Comment: Rough estimate : 8 months

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity's sake, I would break it up in a pure frontend project and a pure backend project. The workload will be slightly more since you have to write a messaging service inbetween, but longterm, you can reuse that backend for other frontends / services.

Since you're going to use RabbitMQ for messaging, you might as well have them separate and when the load gets heavy, you just plug in another frontend instance or when the backend starts to suffer, startup another backend or when the queue suffers, startup another instance of RabbitMQ.

For the frontend project I would use something like XMLRPC, your GWT code will then communicate via XMLRPC with your Java code and voila, you can test the endpoints right there, develop by just plugging in dummy data right there and work on the frontend even without the presence of a database or queue system. This also allows you to start both projects at the same time.

So basically from a point of plug-ability and ease of testing and since you're planning to use RabbitMQ, two separate projects, if there was only one project containing both the frontend and the backend, then there would be no/little need for RabbitMQ and for every frontend you're starting up, you'd be starting up another backend which might be a waste of memory.